# TypeLoadException occurred when drag-and-drop a User Control into VS Designer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I created a customized ListView class, BinableListView, which inherits from ListView. I was able to drag and drop the custom ListView into a Form in the designer window. Now, I am trying to add the custom ListView in another User Control first, and add that User Control into the form. However, VS displayed TypeLoadException when I drag and drop the User Control into the Form in designer. Does anyone has suggestion what might have happened?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 targeting .NET runtime 3.5.

Comment: Which type are you getting a `TypeLoadException` for?

Comment: The type is my custom ListView, BinableListView

Answer (score 0):

Is the user control in a separate library? If yes, make sure that the library can be compiled successfully and that in your reference you have set CopyLocal to true.

Also check for additional libraries which are used by your user control which may be missing as references in your application project.

Sometimes it helps just cleaning and rebuilding everything and trying again.